# ArrayOutOfBounds testing code not working

Tags: java, arrays

I have been having trouble with testing for an arrayOutOfBounds exception. In the following code, my if... else statements are supposed to prevent the knight from moving off my chess board, however I still get the exception. Does anyone see my mistake here? Any help is appreciated!

```
public int[][] firstMoveChoice() {
int knight = 0;    
x += 1;
y += 2;

if (x > board.length) { // this tests to make sure the knight does not move off the row
    System.out.println("Cannot move off board on x axis");
    x -= 1;
}
else if (y > board.length) { // this tests to make sure the knight does not move off the column
    System.out.println("Cannot move off board on y axis");
    y -= 2;
}
else { // this moves the knight when the above statements are false
    board[x][y] = ++knight;
    System.out.println("This executed");
}

for(int[] row : board) {
    printRow(row);
}
}
```

Here is the last board that got printed:

```
This executed
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  3  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  0  4  0  
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
at knightstour.Moves.firstMoveChoice(Moves.java:53)
at knightstour.KnightsTour.main(KnightsTour.java:24)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Here is my ChessBoard class:

```
public class ChessBoard {

int[][] board;

public ChessBoard() {
    this.board = new int[8][8];
}
}
```

And here is my printRow method:

```
public static void printRow(int[] row) {
    for (int i : row) {
        System.out.print(i);
        System.out.print("  ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This is my Main method. When it calls starting location, all it does is assign board[0][0] to 1. Let me know if you want the actual code though.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MoveKnight myKnight = new MoveKnight();
    myKnight.startingLocation();
    myKnight.firstMoveChoice();
    myKnight.firstMoveChoice();
    myKnight.firstMoveChoice();
    myKnight.firstMoveChoice(); // this moves the knight off the board
}
```

Comment: `>` needs to be `>=` - in the last iteration, `y` is `8` and `board.length` is also `8`, so the condition is not satisfied with `>`

Comment: At no point did you instantiate your board, can you show the code with your declaration of the board object, please?

Comment: >= Means Greater Than or Equal to; therefore, when you reach your designed maximum, it loops for one more time because the boolean statement is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `if` condition must be '>='. Try:

```
if (x >= board.length) { // This tests to make sure the knight does not move off the row
    System.out.println("Cannot move off board on x axis");
    x -= 1;
}
else if (y >= board.length) { // This tests to make sure the knight does not move off the column
    System.out.println("Cannot move off board on y axis");
    y -= 2;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I just tried that and it works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you enumerate rows/cols from 0, while "length" returns true length of the array, so test of form

```
if x > board.length
```

is incorrect, as only `x` being in `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}` should be correct, and in your case also 8 is not bigger than `8`. Change these conditions to

```
if x >= board.length
```

the same applies for `y`

Comment: I appreciate you explaining that to me! Thank you for your time!